# Pandas Multi/Hierarchical Indexing - performing arithmetic operation between columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
arr = np.random.randint(10, 99, (4,4))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['X','Y'],['A','B']])
```

And it looks like this:

```
    X       Y    
    A   B   A   B
0  76  78  29  24
1  34  80  83  56
2  56  44  40  30
3  16  38  45  93
```

For all rows where A < B in X, I want to do A - B in Y. How do I do that?

I did this to filter and select A and B from Y

```
df[df['X']['A'] < df['X']['B']].loc[:, ('Y', ['A', 'B'])]

    Y
    A   B
0   29  24
1   83  56
3   45  93
```

But I am lost on how to do A - B.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: For the above example, the output should be 5, 27, and -48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select columns by tuples for `MultiIndex` like:

```
np.random.seed(20)
arr = np.random.randint(10, 99, (4,4))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['X','Y'],['A','B']])
print (df)
    X       Y    
    A   B   A   B
0  25  38  19  30
1  85  32  81  44
2  50  95  36  93
3  26  72  26  17

mask = df[('X','A')].lt(df[('X','B')])
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool

s = df.loc[mask, ('Y','A')].sub(df.loc[mask, ('Y','B')])
print (s)
0   -11
2   -57
3     9
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to subtract and update `A` with the result, you can do so by indexing as:

```
m = (df[('X','A')] < df[('X','B')])
df.loc[m,('Y','A')] = df.loc[m,('Y','A')] - df.loc[m,('Y','B')]
```

---

```
print(df)
    X       Y    
    A   B   A   B
0  77  67  55  87
1  36  85  26  50
2  77  14  62  89
3  88  33  82  44
```